# Resolving variable in jsp page

Tags: eclipse, jsp, github, commit, resolve

I committed my [eclipse](/questions/tagged/eclipse) project on *GitHub* and since then, every `jsp` is creating an issue.

[image: Variable not resolved]

I tried Git staging and everything is synced with *GitHub*.
Website is working fine too.
But I can't resolve the variable or any java object.

Answer (score 0):

May be your project class-path missing the jar file `Servlet-api.jar`. Please check and add manually this jar into your classpath, then restart the server.

Comment: Did. Still same problem. Website is working fine. It's just the view that is causing problem.

Comment: You haven't added the JRE libraries to your IDE. Please share your library structure.

Comment: click on your project and go to build path configure updated jre path and Select the library type to add

Comment: I think you are right. I get two message. First : Build path entry is missing: org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/jre1.8.0_131.    Second : JRE System Library [jre1.8.0_132](unbound)

Comment: The problem is in jsp page in the java code between <% %>. The thing still works fine. Problem is every EE project whether committed to github or not. They were fine yesterday.

Comment: If you think my answer or comments are helpful means please up vote

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
Java Library Unbound problem
Went to Java Build Path in properties.
selected the conflicting JRE Library
Go To Edit-> Selected Workspace Default JRE.
Click OK.
Done.

Comment: I'd suggest setting it to an acceptable Execution Environment instead. It's equally portable, but still lets you have some control over which JRE you need.